# Login is currently incompatible with git bash/cygwin

Tags: git, bash, deployment

I just download this version Git-2.6.1-64-bit.exe my OS is windows 10 64bit.. why I cannot still log in it? is Git-2.6.1-64-bit.exe the latest one?

before it was MINWG32 now updated become MINWG64 but still I cannot login..help me solve this issues

I don't have any solution for this instead to use the cmd.exe.... but I need the flow of it...coz some of the commands cannot run in this environment...it's a big difference between a Linux-like environment... please post procedure/steps in deploying apps in heroku.

IT SAYS : 
Login is currently incompatible with git bash/cygwin
In the meantime, login via cmd.exe
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/issues/84

Comment: What's the question here? That linked issue clearly indicates what the problem is, what the workaround is, how you can use git bash/cygwin even with the workaround, etc. What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 32):

login through the windows command prompt first, then you will be able to run heroku commands on git Bash.

Answer (score 15):

Simple fix.  Install Heroku on Windows machine as per the site instructions.  Then, with Git Bash closed, open the Windows "Command Prompt" and type "heroku login".  You will be prompted for your Heroku username and password and you're in!  Close the command prompt and use bash as per normal.

Comment: When I follow these steps and go back to Git Bash to execute "git push heroku master", I get: "fatal 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository". Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Actually, an update (to clarify): the above fatal error happened after I had first issued "heroku create" from another cmd line from the one where I did the push. When I issue the create and follow it with the push from the same Git Bash command line it seems to work!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of typing **heroku login** , i had to type **winpty heroku login** . And that solved my problem.

i.e

```
winpty heroku login
```

Comment: I had to run: winpty heroku.cmd login

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ winpty heroku login
```

Source:

https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/84

Answer (score 1):

First, the latest releases are listed at https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Download [`PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.7.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit.7z.exe), uncompress it to c:\git2.7.0, and add to your path:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\git2.7.0\bin;c:\git2.7.0;c:\git2.7.0\usr\bin
```

Then launch git-cmd or git-bash.

Answer (score 1):

I always find CMDER works well and works first time with heroku, just a suggestion.

You can find the link [here](http://cmder.net/)

Answer (score 0):

login from windows cmd. I have been successful to login from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Ozesh' solution, it seems best to define the following alias in your `.bashrc`-file to avoid the need for remembering to prefix the command with `winpty`:

```
alias heroku='winpty heroku.cmd'
```

(This was suggested in [this response](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/84#issuecomment-388320558) to the issue mentioned by @anjandash.)