# Push From Git Bash to Heroku

Tags: windows, git, bash, heroku

I want to push a project I created to Heroku from Git. I'm running windows and have the Git Bash shell installed as well as the Heroku CLI. Running this from Git Bash shows my Git version:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.14.1.windows.1
```

However, when I try from that same Git Bash shell to create my application on Heroku as a remote Git repo, I get an error:

```
$ heroku create
bash: heroku: command not found
```

So instead I created my application on Heroku from a regular windows cmd terminal and that worked (i.e., when I log into heroku I see the remote repo). But when I try to do a `git push` from the windows cmd terminal it does not recognize git:

```
C:\myapp>git push heroku master
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Whereas when I try to do a `git push` from the git bash shell, I get this error indicating perhaps it doesn't know what to make of heroku:

```
$ git push heroku master
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

So it seems my regular windows cmd terminal recognizes heroku, but my Git bash terminal does not. How do I configure Git bash to recognize the Heroku command?

Note: When I do a `env | grep path` from the Git bash shell the results do include my *C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin* directory, so Git is aware of my Heroku path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! It required the following 3 steps/considerations:

- First, I followed john g's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792563/login-is-currently-incompatible-with-git-bash-cygwin/34797965), which is to close Git Bash and login to Heroku via a windows cmd terminal, then use Git Bash as per normal.
- Second, when issuing a `heroku` command from Git Bash on Windows, include the extension, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path#). I.e., issue `heroku.cmd create` (instead of just `heroku create`).
- Third, apparently the `git push heroku master` command must be issued from the same Git Bash terminal where you just issued `heroku.cmd create`. When I had issued it from a separate terminal I got an error saying "*'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository*".

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not that git would not push to heroku, but that you actually haven't installed git on your system, as the message you posted suggests.

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

At [heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) there is a whole article about pushing to git, if you experience further problems after installing git, you might find a solution there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, I do have git installed. I've modified my question above to try to clarify that.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your `.git/config` file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this, in hopes that it may help others and save them the same trouble I had. This was driving me mad and I tried every solution I could manage to find on the issue. Spent several hours trying to trouble-shoot it. What it actually ended up being was a conflict with my internet security, specifically Comodo Internet Security Premium 10. I received no warning, it just automatically added it to a blocked list on first execution. If you are running internet security software, especially on a Windows machine, this very well could be your issue. Remove the command file found at C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\heroku\client\bin\heroku.cmd from any block list, as well as any other executables from heroku that may be on the list.